# Devise NameError in Devise/registrationsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I followed the setting up devise tutorial, but now when I go to

```
/users/sign_up
```

I get

```
Devise NameError in Devise/registrationsController#new
```

same if I go to

```
/users/sign_in
```

I get

```
/NameError in Devise/sessionsController#create
```

I have scrapped my models for errors or typos. I don't really get it because it looks like it is having trouble with the "devise controllers" but there aren't any of those in my /app file, so I assume those files (like on git) are running somewhere in the background.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late to answer, but my experience might help someone else out.

I had the same issue with devise & cancan. The solution in my case was simply to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

or

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "devise/registrations"} do
    get '/register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
end
```

Comment: Putting either of those into my routes didn't fix it.

Comment: I never figured this out, but I just started my app over and did the devise part first, then migrated everything from my old app into the new one, checking to see when devise ever failed. It never did, and I saw no differences between the two apps, so chalk this one up to the gremlins

Comment: By any chance where you also using the CanCan gem for roles and permissions?